# Mismatching locale identifiers for default languages in Xcode and App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

The list of "main" languages that can be added in Xcode in the project's Info panel (i.e. the ones that can be added without diving into the long submenu) are basically the same that can be added in App Store Connect (except that Xcode also lists `Chinese (Hong Kong) (zh-HK)` and `English (India) (en-IN)` which don't exist in App Store Connect). But I noticed that the locale identifiers sometimes refer to different regions: e.g. Xcode has `Spanish (es)` and `Spanish (Latin America) (es-419)` while App Store Connect uses `Spanish (Spain)` and `Spanish (Mexico)` which when downloaded through the App Store Connect API have the identifiers `en-ES` and `en-MX`.

Forgive my ignorance, but does that mean that the language used in Latin America and Mexico is the same? Or should I instead select the Mexico variant in Xcode so that the locale identifiers used in the app and on the App Store match?

All the mismatching locales are (Xcode first, App Store Connect second):

`ar` vs. `ar-SA`

`de` vs `de-DE`

`en` vs `en-US`

`es` vs `es-ES`

`es-419` vs `es-MX`

`fr` vs `fr-FR`

`nl` vs `nl-NL`

Comment: What does "added in App Store Connect" mean? My app has localizations but I don't "add" anything in App Store Connect.

Comment: If you want your app to have a localized App Store page (app name, description, screenshots etc.), you have to explicitly add any extra language in App Store Connect in the Apps section and enter the respective data.

Comment: Aha, okay. Then I'd say there's no reason to worry about any "correspondence" because there's nothing to correspond. Localization (internal languages) and App Store Connect display are unrelated. The App Store depends upon specific country-based agreements.

Comment: My worries are that one of those languages with mismatching identifiers could be shown for some users on the App Store, and then not be used in the app, or vice versa.

Comment: But what I'm saying is there is no mismatch because there is no match. What you're configuring in the AppStore stays in the App Store.

Comment: I'm aware that the App Store data and the app itself can be configured differently. But users who see a language on the App Store would also expect the same language to be used in the app itself, and it would be disappointing for them if after buying an app they found out that with their current settings they would see a different language, perhaps one they don't understand. Which is why I'm wondering if using the default languages is ok, or I really have to pay attention to matching the locale identifiers to make sure that these expectations are met.